# Erro com código JavaScript, meu código duplica o dado do input

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou escrevendo um código de uma Urna Eletrônica, utilizando métodos que eu conheço (tirei essa ideia de um video no youtube).

Observem o código...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/element.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="urna">
            <div class="display">
                <div class="informations">
                    <div class="description">
                        <div class="yourVote">SEU VOTO PARA:</div>
                        <div class="voteType"></div>
                        <div class="inputGrid"></div>
                        <div class="informationsVote"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-grid">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="legend">
                    <p># LEGENDA #</p>
                    <p>CONFIRMA para CONFIRMAR seu voto</p>
                    <p>CORRIGE para REINICIAR seu voto</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="keyboards">
                <table class="keyboards-numbers">
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">1</button></td>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">2</button></td>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">3</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">4</button></td>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">5</button></td>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">6</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">7</button></td>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">8</button></td>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">9</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><button class="keyboard-number">0</button></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="keyboards-actions">
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="white">BRANCO</button></td>
                        <td><button class="reset">CORRIGE</button></td>
                        <td><button class="confirm">CONFIRMA</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="/assets/js/stages.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes flashing {
    0% {opacity: 0.2;}
    50% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0.2;}
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(../img/background.jpg);
}

.urna {
    display: flex;
    padding: 2.5rem;
    background: #DBD5C9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 12px 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
    box-shadow: 10px 12px 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.display {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    width: 68rem;
    height: 50rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #E8E8E8, #C1C1C1);
    border: 0.2rem solid #000;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.keyboards {
    margin-left: 2.5rem;
    background: #403A3A;
}

.keyboards-numbers {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2rem;
}

.keyboards-numbers button {
    font-size: 4.8rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.keyboards-actions tr{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2rem;
    gap: 1.5rem
}

.keyboards-actions button {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.9rem 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.white {
    background: #FFF;
}

.reset {
    background: #F09046;
}

.confirm {
    background: #48C079;
}

.informations {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
}

.img-grid .img-candidate {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0.2rem solid #000;
}

.img-grid h2 {
    background: #FFF;
    margin-top: -0.21rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.8rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.img-candidate img {
    width: 100%;
}

.informations .img-vice-candidate {
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
    border: 0.2rem solid #000;
}

.img-vice-candidate img {
    width: 100%;
}

.legend {
    padding: 1.2rem;
    border-top: 0.1rem solid #000;
}

.legend p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.description {
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.yourVote {
    margin: 2rem 0;
    font-size: 4rem;
    height: 4.7rem;
}

.voteType {
    margin: 2rem 0;
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.inputGrid {
    display: flex;
    margin: 3rem 0 6rem 0;
}

.inputGrid input {
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 6.5rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid #000;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
}

.informationsVote p {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.flashing {
    animation-name: flashing;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.null-vote {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Agora o código JavaScript Stages (com o possíveis candidatos):

```
let stages = [
    {
        title: "VEREADOR",
        numbers: 5,
        candidates: [
            {
                number: "78568",
                name: "Lucas Corrêa",
                match: "PSOL",
                photo: [{url:"assets/img/78568.png", legend: "VEREADOR"}]
            },
            {
                number: "39665",
                name: "Mariana Catani",
                match: "PSDB",
                photo: [{url:"assets/img/39665.png", legend: "VEREADOR"}]
            },
            {
                number: "45863",
                name: "Marcelo Santos",
                match: "PT",
                photo: [{url:"assets/img/45863.png", legend: "VEREADOR"}]
            },
            {
                number: "84569",
                name: "Paola Borges",
                match: "PSDB",
                photo: [{url:"assets/img/84569.png", legend: "VEREADOR"}]
            },
            {
                number: "45879",
                name: "Isabel Waiss",
                match: "PSOL",
                photo: [{url:"assets/img/45879.png", legend: "VEREADOR"}]
            },
            {
                number: "75698",
                name: "Rafa Figueiredo",
                match: "PSOL",
                photo: [{url:"assets/img/75698.png", legend: "VEREADOR"}]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        title: "PREFEITO",
        numbers: 2,
        candidates: [
            {
                number: "27",
                name: "Lucas Corrêa",
                match: "PSOL",
                vice: "Cintia Fraga",
                photo: [{url:"assets/img/27.png", legend: "PREFEITO"}, {url:"assets/img/44.png", legend: "VICE-PREFEITO", small: true}] 
            },
            {
                number: "45",
                name: "Lucas Corrêa",
                match: "PMDB",
                vice: "Dioney Pinheiro",
                photo: [{url:"assets/img/45.png", legend: "VICE"}, {url:"assets/img/98.png", legend: "VICE-PREFEITO", small: true}] 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Por fim o código do Script (O PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI):

```
let yourVote = document.querySelector(".yourVote");                     //ARMAZENA A QUERY DO "SEU VOTO PARA"
let office = document.querySelector(".voteType");                       //ARMAZENA A QUERY DO "CARGO DO VOTO"
let descritionVote = document.querySelector(".informationsVote");       //ARMAZENA A QUERY DAS INFORMÇÕES
let legend = document.querySelector(".legend");                         //ARMAZENA A QUERY DA LEGENDA
let containerImg = document.querySelector(".img-grid");                 //ARMAZENA A QUERY DAS IMAGENS
let inputGrid = document.querySelector(".inputGrid");                   //ARMAZENA A QUERY DA GRID DE INPUTS
let buttons = document.querySelector(".keyboards");                     //ARMAZENA A QUERY DOS BOTÕES

let currentStage = 0;
let numberCandidate = "";
let statusWhite = false;

function start() {
    let stage = stages[currentStage];
    
    let qntdInputs = "";
    numberCandidate = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < stage.numbers; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            qntdInputs += '<input class="inputItem flashing"></input>';
        } else {
            qntdInputs += '<input class="inputItem"></input>';
        }
    }

    yourVote.style.display = "none";
    legend.style.display = "none";

    containerImg.innerHTML = "";
    descritionVote.innerHTML = "";

    office.innerHTML = stage.title;
    inputGrid.innerHTML = qntdInputs;

    btnClick();
}

function attInterface() {
    let stage = stages[currentStage];
    let candidate = stage.candidates.filter((item) => {
        if(item.number === numberCandidate) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })

    if(candidate.length > 0) {
        candidate = candidate[0];
        yourVote.style.display = "block";
        legend.style.display = "block";
        descritionVote.innerHTML = `<p>NOME: ${candidate.name}</p><p>PARTIDO: ${candidate.match}</p>`;

        let photos = "";
        for (let i in candidate.photo) {
            photos += `<div class="img-candidate"><img src="${candidate.photo[i].url}" alt=""><h2>${candidate.photo[i].legend}</h2></div>`;
        }

        containerImg.innerHTML = photos;
    } else {
        yourVote.style.display = "block";
        legend.style.display = "block";
        descritionVote.innerHTML = '<div class="null-vote flashing">VOTO NULO</div>';
    }
}

function caracterToDisplay(value) {
    let inputList = document.querySelector(".inputItem.flashing");

    if(inputList !== null) {
        inputList.value = value;
        inputList.innerHTML = value;

        inputList.classList.remove("flashing");
        if(inputList.nextElementSibling !== null) {
            inputList.nextElementSibling.classList.add("flashing");
        } else {
            attInterface();
        }
    }
}

function btnClick() {
    buttons.addEventListener("click", event => {
        element = event.target;

        if (element.classList.contains("keyboard-number")) {
            numberCandidate += element.innerHTML;
            caracterToDisplay(element.innerHTML);
        }
        if (element.classList.contains("reset")) {
            clean();
        }
        if (element.classList.contains("white")) {
            white();
        }
        if (element.classList.contains("confirm")) {
            confirmVote();
        }
    })
}

function candidate() {

}

function white() {
    if(numberCandidate === "") {
        statusWhite = true;
        yourVote.style.display = "block";
        legend.style.display = "block";
        inputGrid.innerHTML = "";
        descritionVote.innerHTML = '<div class="null-vote flashing">VOTO EM BRANCO</div>';
    } else {
        alert("Para votar em BRANCO você deve primeiro corrigir.")
    }
}

function clean() {
    start();
}

function confirmVote() {
    let stage = stages[currentStage];

    let confirmedVote = false;

    if(statusWhite === true) {
        confirmedVote = true;
    } else if (numberCandidate.length === stage.numbers) {
        confirmedVote = true;
    }

    if(confirmedVote === true) {
        currentStage++;
        if(stages[currentStage] !== undefined) {
            start();
        } else {
            console.log("Fim");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Você deve preencher todos os campos, para passar para proxima etapa!");
    }
}

start();
```

Quando estou preenchendo a urna, e erro a digitação eu tenho a possibilidade de corrigir, clicando no botão CORRIGE, porem quando eu clico nele simplesmente os próximos clique nos botões numéricos, insere valores duplicados nos inputs... E se eu clicar novamente no corrige, insere valores quadruplicados... Estou a 5h nesses código travado, queria muito a ajuda para entender oque esta acontecendo. Valeu!!!

ATUALIZANDO: Após um tempo analisando, vi que estava rodando duas funções de captura de eventos ao mesmo tempo, como posso para que uma se encerre para iniciar outra... A função btnClick

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Veja também como fazer um [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Creio que refatorando os laços condicionais da função btnClick() seu problema seja resolvido.
Tente algo do tipo:

```
if (element.classList.contains("keyboard-number")) {
     numberCandidate += element.innerHTML;
     caracterToDisplay(element.innerHTML);
    }
else if (element.classList.contains("reset")) {
     clean();
    }
else if (element.classList.contains("white")) {
     white();
    }
else {
     confirmVote();
    }
```

Acontecerá validações dentro das condições descritas, uma a uma. Anteriormente, uma ou mais condições poderiam ser validadas incorretamente como verdadeiras.

Comment: Descobri oque estava acontecendo e usei uma "gambiarra para resolver", ao clicar no botão confirma, ou corrige, basicamente ele chamava a função Start(), porem a função start inicia a função BtnClick que é uma função de captura de evento, ai notei que estava rodando 2 capturas de eventos ao mesmo tempo, a de quando inicia o programa e a de quando clico para corrigir... Para resolver criei uma função igual a Start(), com o nome de  start2() porem tirei a função de dentro dela de iniciar a btnClick()... Agora quando clico em CORRIGE ele chama a função start2() e não fica rodando 2 função juntas